# PHP Error logging, web vs. command-line

Tags: php, apache

When I log messages via `error_log()` in my PHP web app, the messages get logged in Apache's `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

When I log messages the same way in a PHP command-line app, the messages go to PHP's own php-error.log

Is there a way to log messages to PHP's error log from a PHP web app?

Comment: Are you running on a hosted site? Or do you have your own server?

Comment: We have our own server (Centos 6), but it's the same situation on my Development pc (OSX 10.11)

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file look for this parameter

```
error_log =
```

And set it to whatever filename and location you want.

Of course if you want to seperate your web PHP error logs from your PHP CLI error logs then you need to remember that there are normally 2 `php.ini` files

One that is used by Apache/PHP and the other that is used by PHP CLI possibly `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

If you change the `php.ini` file used by the PHP CLI you can have a different file name completely used for the error logging from PHP CLI scripts

Look for

```
error_log =
```

and change to

```
error_log = /var/log/php_cli_errors.log
```

for example.

Comment: I don't think you've fully read my question.  I'm already logging from PHP (for non-Web apps)

Comment: Ahh I think you are right, give me a couple of mins I see what you need now